# Laravel routing without appending any prefix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, subdomain

I have a path in Laravel it is like *subdomain.mydomain.com/admin/login*

I am trying to call

**subdomain.mydomain.com** and need to get the login page straight.

Currently, it's not working

This is the function I am using in **routerserviceprovider.php**

```
protected function mapAdminRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('subdomain.mydomain.com')
         ->prefix('admin')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
}
```

and in **admin.php** there is a resource group shows like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    //Login Routes...
  Route::view('login','admin.login');
});
```

can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Add following route

```
Route::get('/',function(){ return view('login.index'); })->name('admin.login');
```

i hope it helps

Comment: Nope.. it didn't help me. I still have to append "admin" in the end of the subdomain